# OpenCV can't find Gstreamer

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, gstreamer

I had Ubuntu 18 with OpenCV and GStreamer setup correctly. After a while, OpenCV can't detect Gstreamer anymore. I don't remember what I installed in between.

`apt list` reports:

```
gstreamer1.0-alsa/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0/bionic,now 3.0.26-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-doc/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 all [installed]
gstreamer1.0-gl/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-gtk3/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-libav/bionic-updates,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-packagekit/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.1.9-1ubuntu2.18.04.6 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/bionic-updates,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly/bionic-updates,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-qt5/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-tools/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-vaapi/bionic-updates,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-x/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 1.14.5-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 amd64 [installed]
```

`python3 -c "import cv2; print(cv2.getBuildInformation())"` output is:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 4.5.1 =====================================
  Version control:               4.5.1

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2021-01-02T13:13:24Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.15.0-1077-gcp x86_64
    CMake:                       3.18.4
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /bin/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (15 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (29 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (4 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ standard:                11
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/lib/ccache/compilers/c++  (ver 9.3.1)
    C++ flags (Release):         -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/lib/ccache/compilers/cc
    C flags (Release):           -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -Wl,-strip-all   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippicv.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libippiw.a -L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  
    ccache:                      YES
    Precompiled headers:         NO
    Extra dependencies:          ade /lib64/libpng.so /lib64/libz.so dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf libjpeg-turbo libwebp libtiff libopenjp2 IlmImf quirc ippiw ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python3 stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI: 
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.7)
    JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.6-62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
    PNG:                         /lib64/libpng.so (ver 1.5.13)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.3.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (58.109.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.61.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.60.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.8.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2020.0.0 Gold [2020.0.0]
           at:                   /tmp/pip-req-build-_a0ur5ao/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2020.0.0)
              at:                /tmp/pip-req-build-_a0ur5ao/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /tmp/pip-req-build-_a0ur5ao/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/bin/python (ver 3.6.12)
    Libraries:                   libpython3.6m.a (ver 3.6.12)
    numpy:                       /tmp/pip-build-env-hw7xf5yk/overlay/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.3)
    install path:                python

  Python (for build):            /bin/python2.7

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /tmp/pip-req-build-_a0ur5ao/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I used to compile OpenCV with

```
cmake \
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D WITH_TBB=ON \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
-D WITH_V4L=ON \
-D WITH_QT=OFF \
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
-D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
-D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv.pc \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-4.4.0/modules \
-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 \
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=$CUDA_ARCH_BIN \
..
```

That used to work. I tried reinstalling but it is not working anymore.

Attached screenshot of some output from installation:
[image]

EDIT: I am using an EC@ instance. Output of `gst-launch-1.0 -e -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0  ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! autovideosin` is:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAutoVideoSink:autovideosink0: Could not initialise Xv output
Additional debug info:
xvimagesink.c(1773): gst_xv_image_sink_open (): /GstXvImageSink:autovideosink0-actual-sink-xvimage:
Could not open display (null)
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Cannot identify device '/dev/video0'.
Additional debug info:
v4l2_calls.c(609): gst_v4l2_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
system error: No such file or directory
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

EDIT2: among the `dev` packages I installed I have:

```
sudo apt install -y libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
cpio libusb-1.0-0-dev libtag-extras1 libgl-dev gobject-introspection libgsl23 bison flex libdrm-dev build-essential lbzip2 make cmake g++ wget unzip pkg-config yasm checkinstall \
libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libavresample-dev libswscale-dev libeigen3-dev libglew-dev libgstreamer1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev \
gstreamer1.0-vaapi gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools libgstrtspserver-1.0-0 \
gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev x264 libgtk-3-dev libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev \
libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libxine2-dev libv4l-dev v4l-utils \
libfluidsynth1 libnettle6 libopenexr22 libglib2.0 python3-gi libfdk-aac1 libfaac0 xkb-data libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjpeg8-dev libjpeg-turbo8-dev libxine2-dev libdc1394-22-dev libv4l-dev \
v4l-utils qv4l2 v4l2ucp libatlas-base-dev libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev liblapacke-dev gfortran libgtk2.0-dev qt5-default libqt5opengl5-dev python3-dev
```

Comment: Do you have the gstreamer packages ending in -dev? Those are the packages you need to compile OpenCV

Comment: See above with information

Comment: Did you find what you were missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should see if gstreamer is working properly in linux command line first. Try something like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0  ! video/x-raw,format=UYVY,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1 ! autovideosink
```

That can be run directly from linux command line. If that works (you can see a window pop up with the video feed), then it's probably just a matter of properly reconfiguring opencv again, try this:

https://medium.com/@galaktyk01/how-to-build-opencv-with-gstreamer-b11668fa09c

If that doesn't work, you may need to uninstall and reinstall gstreamer, you can comment with any error messages you get.

Comment: I am on an EC2 instance (AWS server) so I cannot open any window. Is there any other way?

Comment: I see, so there's no actual camera connected. Well, even though you got error messages with gstreamer it still seems to be present and working on the remote device. Did you already try recompiling opencv with gstreamer as in the link? If that's what you've been trying to avoid, unfortunately I think whatever you may have configured inbetween could have broken the integration. If you want to avoid re-doing that in the future, then after fixing you can use checkinstall to create a .deb binary that installs quickly.